# How to make image fit the whole screen in android?

Tags: android, image, layout

I tried to make image taken to fit the whole screen size. My XML for the activity layout is below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

My code to display the image:

```
private void showImage(String imageName){
    String directory = "/sdcard/DCIM/cat/" + imageName;
    File  imageFile = new File(directory);
    if(imageFile.exists()){
        Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());

        //rotating the bitmap by 90 degree clockwise. Assume the bitmap is 270 degree clockwise.
        Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
        mtx.preRotate(90);

        int w = imageBitmap.getWidth();
        int h = imageBitmap.getHeight();

        imageBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageBitmap,0,0,w,h,mtx,false);
        imageBitmap = imageBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,true);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);

    }
```

The output on the scree is as below:
 [image: Screen capture of the activity]

As you all might observe, there are blank spaces at both left and right side of the image. Any way to make the image fit perfectly onto the screen?

Comment: Try to use android:scaleType="fitXY" properties for ImageView.

Comment: thanks!!! the solves my problem. :)

Answer (score 4):

Add `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` to the `<ImageView>` declaration. It will fill the whole space and cut off extra parts.

Comment: Actually, that's `centerCrop`, not `cropCenter`, and I had forgotten about this option -- thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use [android:scaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) properties fill image :

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

**OR**

```
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY)
```

Answer (score 1):

With [setScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) attribute you can do it.

something like this:

```
imgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER); // OR FIT_XY
```

Answer (score 1):

Use either

```
android:scaleType = "fitCenter" //This will preserve the aspect ratio of image
```

or

```
android:scaleType="fitXY" //This won't preserve the aspect ratio of image
```